# Dissable pid-namespace init process signal handler restriction

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kill, namespace

*Ubuntu 16.04 / Linux version 4.4.0-47-generic / gcc version 5.4.0*

I want to implement a container using linux cgroups and part of the implementation was to run the process into a new pid-namespace.

From [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html)

> Only signals for which the "init" process has established a signal
>          handler can be sent to the "init" process by other members of the PID
>          namespace.  This restriction applies even to privileged processes,
>          and prevents other members of the PID namespace from accidentally
>          killing the "init" process.

Unfortunately this applies to the init process itself. For example, if an assertion breaks into the init process and it doesn't have a handler for sig6 the assert code will send a sig11.

Is there any way to disable this feature (at least in the case where the init process sends signals to itself). I can't enforce the init process to have signal handlers for this kind of scenarios and I want to know why did the process stop.

One small hack can be to create a dummy init process which will forward somehow the signal from the target program, but it's there a non-hackish solution for this?

Comment: A pod-namespace shouldn't be dissed unless it has been fully understood.